# How to correctly generate XAML in multi file templates in resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, templates, resharper

I have a multi file template with 4 template files implementing an MVVM setup. The result is

[image]

The files are generated in the same order as they have been defined in the template. However the obvious error is that the FeedbackFormView.xaml.cs is not a child of FeedbackFormView.xaml as it should be in a visual studio project. How to get this to automatically work? I know I can manually edit the csproj file and set the **DependentUpon** property but this is not a nice workaround.

Using Resharper version

[image]

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper doesn't support automatically setting files as being nested. You can use the File Nesting extension for Visual Studio to allow you to do this with a right click, and I think you can also set up rules to allow for automatic nesting. You can get it from Visual Studio's Tools and Updates extension manager. Here's the [gallery page](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ebde8fb-26d8-4374-a0eb-1e4e2665070c), and the [GitHub project](https://github.com/madskristensen/FileNesting)